# JMeter: How to retrieve Summary Report?

Tags: logging, report, jmeter

After a load test was done in JMeter, it closed due to some reason before I could save the summary report. Is there any way to retrieve the values now?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you running your load tests using JMeter GUI - please stop and switch to non-GUI command-line mode as AWT GUI threads become flaky on loads with 50+ users.

If you run JMeter test as follows:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l test.jtl
```

the results will be stored in `test.jtl` file as they will be returned and you won't loose a single byte even if JMeter dies unexpectedly.

See [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) for more JMeter launch options. Perhaps you'll find something more convenient but please stop using JMeter GUI for anything but tests development or debugging

Answer (score 0):

Please follow "Dmitri T" advice.

For your question, If you had not updated your listener to save the result while running in GUI mode, I doubt that you might have lost the result. However jmeter.log file will get created in the same location where you have your .jmx file. Please check if it has anything you are looking for.